# Passing an extra parameter in the middle of a Promise chain

Tags: javascript, promise, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I need to throw in a `userID` param in the middle of a promise chain(it is the only promise that needs it). All the promises should execute in a synchronous order.

SideNote- All the similar examples on stackoverflow are all a bit different- like using lambda functions(I use declared functions).So I'm still not quite sure.

```
var initialize = function(userID) {
      var firstPromise = Module2.getFirstPromise();
          firstPromise.then(getSecondPromise)
         .then(getThirdPromise)                     
         .then(getFourthPromise)  //<----Fourth promise needs userID
         .then(getFifthPromise)
         .then(Utils.initializeComplete);
  }
```

All the promises are functions that look like this:

```
var thirdPromise = function() {
   return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      //fetch data
        //On Return, Store it
         resolve() //Nothing needed to passed down from this promise
      });

    });

}
```

I'm trying this, and it "works", but I'm not sure if that is how I am "suppose" to handle something like this. :)

```
var initialize = function(userID) {
      var firstPromise = Module2.getFirstPromise();
          firstPromise.then(getSecondPromise)
         .then(getThirdPromise)                     
         .then(function(){ return fourthPromise(userID)})
         .then(getFourthPromise)
         .then(Utils.initializeComplete);
  }
```

Note: `getFirstPromise` is coming from a different module in my code. That shouldn't be important to the question though :)

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Are you getting an error or an unexpected outcome?

Comment: It's really confusing, you have `firstPromise` which clearly refers to a promise, and then `secondPromise` and so on which seem to refer to functions. I would recommend changing that naming.

Comment: Aside from the other comments, your approach of passing an inline function with scope to access `userID` is fine, and a recognised pattern.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I described what all the other functions looked like in the second snippet. Not sure how i can make it clearer but I'm up for suggestions.

Comment: @NickPineda: You don't think `firstPromise` being a promise and `secondPromise` being a *function* is confusing?! As for suggestions, look at my answer.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I think I see what you are saying. Since the return is always wrapped in a promise that part gets confusing. Would i.e. "getSecondPromise" be better?

Comment: @NickPineda: That would be my take, yeah. (In fact, it's exactly what I used in my answer. :-) )

Comment: @T.J.Crowder the things I say when I'm still coding at 4:29am. haha!

Comment: @NickPineda: :-) I must be getting old, instead of staying up coding to 4:29 a.m., I go to bed and then *get up* so I can be coding at 4:29 a.m.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder either way, coding at this time of the day is die hard. :)

Comment: What happens to the result of the third promise? If it doesn't have a result, why do you need to await it at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that `firstPromise` is really a promise but `secondPromise` and so on are actually functions *returning* promises, then yes, what you've done is how you're supposed to do that. [Here's a live example on Babel's REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=true&code=function%20doSomething(userID)%20%7B%0A%20%20getFirstPromise()%0A%20%20%20%20.then(getSecondPromise)%0A%20%20%20%20.then(getThirdPromise)%0A%20%20%20%20.then(()%20%3D%3E%20getFourthPromise(userID))%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Or%20.then(function()%20%7B%20return%20getFourthPromise(userID)%3B%20%7D)%0A%20%20%20%20.then(getFifthPromise)%0A%20%20%20%20.catch(err%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%22Error%3A%20%22%20%2B%20err.message)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%7D%0AdoSomething(%22foo%22)%3B%0Afunction%20getFirstPromise()%20%7B%0A%20%20console.log(%22getFirstPromise%20called%22)%3B%0A%20%20return%20new%20Promise(resolve%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20setTimeout(()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20resolve(%22one%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%200)%3B%0A%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%7D%0Afunction%20getSecondPromise()%20%7B%0A%20%20console.log(%22getSecondPromise%20called%22)%3B%0A%20%20return%20new%20Promise(resolve%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20setTimeout(()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20resolve(%22two%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%200)%3B%0A%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%7D%0Afunction%20getThirdPromise()%20%7B%0A%20%20console.log(%22getThirdPromise%20called%22)%3B%0A%20%20return%20new%20Promise(resolve%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20setTimeout(()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20resolve(%22three%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%200)%3B%0A%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%7D%0Afunction%20getFourthPromise(userID)%20%7B%0A%20%20console.log(%22getFourthPromise%20called%20with%20userID%20%3D%20%22%20%2B%20userID)%3B%0A%20%20return%20new%20Promise(resolve%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20setTimeout(()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20resolve(%22four%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%200)%3B%0A%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%7D%0Afunction%20getFifthPromise()%20%7B%0A%20%20console.log(%22getFifthPromise%20called%22)%3B%0A%20%20return%20new%20Promise(resolve%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20setTimeout(()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20resolve(%22five%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%200)%3B%0A%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%7D%0A), which looks like this:

```
function doSomething(userID) {
  getFirstPromise()
    .then(getSecondPromise)
    .then(getThirdPromise)
    .then(() => getFourthPromise(userID))
    // Or .then(function() { return getFourthPromise(userID); })
    .then(getFifthPromise)
    .catch(err => {
      console.log("Error: " + err.message);
    });
}
doSomething("foo");
function getFirstPromise() {
  console.log("getFirstPromise called");
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve("one");
    }, 0);
  });
}
// and then second, third, fourth (with user ID), and fifth
```

(If you don't use arrow functions, just replace them with the `function` form.)

---

Note the `catch` in the example above. Unless you have a *really good reason not to*, a promise chain should always have a `.catch` if you don't `return` the result.

Answer (score 4):

Your solution is perfectly fine. It might be easier to understand with concrete signatures.

If your `thirdPromise` doesn't take anything and doesn't return anything its signature might be written (pseudocode assuming `a -> b` is a function from a to b) as `_ -> Promise (_)`. If it returns some value `a`, it would be `_ -> Promise (a)`. If it took something and returned something it might be `a -> Promise (b)`

So you can reason about your promise chains as about functions taking some value and returning some other value wrapped in a promise. However, your `fourthPromise` looks differently:

```
fourthPromise : UserId -> a -> Promise (b)
```

Which can be written as:

```
fourthPromise : UserId -> (a -> Promise (b))
```

It takes one parameter *before* becoming an actual promise you can chain. In a way, it's a template of a promise.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the plain `.then` chain in the main function, try to write getFourthPromise as a factory function

```
function getSomethingByUserID(userId) {
   return function() {
        return new Promise(function(resolve) {
            //your actual async job
            resolve('a result');
        });
   };
}
```

Then you will get plan list of `then`s

```
 var firstPromise = Module2.getFirstPromise()
     .then(getSecondPromise)                   
     .then(getSomethingByUserID(userId))
     .then(Utils.initializeComplete);
```

Do not forget that if you missed to provide `userId` to `getSomethingByUserID`, it will not work.